# Pass File From Command Line Java

Tags: java, file, class, sorting, input

So I have a file of integers , one in every line and I want to pass the file as input through args[0] from the command line. 
When I write at the command line java Sorting input.txt I just get "input.txt". But when I write java Sorting 3 2 6 i correctly get 2 3 6. How am I supposed to pass the file? The code is below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Sorting {
public static void main (String args[])
{


    Arrays.sort(args);
    for(String num: args)
        System.out.println(num);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to store the content of the file into an array and then sort the array. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: But  args has taken the content of the file? and I just need to pass it to an array?

Comment: You can pass file contents with shell tools like input piping, but that specifically puts the contents of the file into the standard input stream. You're passing the filename as an argument (no less valid), which means you use that filename to retrieve a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args[]` is just the list of arguments - if you pass in a file, the filename is the argument.

Haven't run this, but try something like:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{

    String filename = args[0];

    // Read the file content to a String
    String fileContent = Files.readString(Paths.get(filename));

    // Split on whitespace (this is a regex, whitespace is \\s in Java - could also use " " for just space)
    // The '+' here denotes "at least 1" whitespace character - added after the discussion below
    String[] elements = fileContent.split("\\s+");
    Arrays.sort(elements);

    for(String num: args)
        System.out.println(num);
}
```

== Edit==

If you want them sorted as integer's you're correct to say that the above treats them as `String`s. You need to parse them as `Int` for that:

public static void main (String args[])
{

```
    String filename = args[0];

    // Read the file content to a String
    String fileContent = Files.readString(Paths.get(filename));

    // Split on whitespace (this is a regex, whitespace is \\s in Java - could also use " " for just space)
    // The '+' here denotes "at least 1" whitespace character - added after the discussion below
    String[] elements = fileContent.split("\\s+");
    int[] intElements = new int[elements.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++) {
        try {
            intElements[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println("Not a number: " + elements[i]);
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(intElements);

    for(int num: intElements)
        System.out.println(num);
```

}

Comment: It just sorts the numbers as String. For example I have 2 4 25 and after that I get 2 25 4..it seems that it compares the first characters and I don;t get an integer sorting

Comment: Yes, you're right - added an update above that parses them to `int`s for you!

Comment: Tried it and I get NumberFormatException at this line : intElements[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);

Comment: Can you print out the numbers in the for() loop, or share the contents of the file? Sounds like you have something in there that's not an int - maybe a double-space or something.

You could also do a try {
    intElements[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("Not a number: " + elements[i]);
}

to print out the problem one

Comment: my file content is this: 2
4
25
80
5
6
8
10
55
44

Comment: But it;s not in the same line.. every int is at different line

Comment: Updated the code in line, as it wasn't readable in the comment - can you try that?

Comment: Wow. With the try catch I get some several Not a number messages , then some zeros and after that I get the numbers sorted.

Comment: Ok - what's in the `Not a number`? just whitespace?

Comment: Exactly. And after the Not a number I get some zeros one at a line. Also if this helps the elements.length is 19 while my numbers are only 10

Comment: I cannot understand why I get the bunch of zeros!

Comment: That's because it's failing to parse all of the strings, and leaving the default value `0` in the `int` array. The more confusing question is why do you have 19 strings. Maybe those aren't single spaces that separate the numbers? Are they newlines or something?

Comment: But after the zeros I get my number sorted correctly !

Comment: I think there must be multiple whitespaces between your numbers - I'll update the code again inline

Comment: There you go - try that

Comment: Also added a comment to explain why I did that

Comment: Wow! That is absolutely correct! Thank you sooo much for your help and of course for spending your time. Have a great one ! Thank you a lot again!!

Comment: No worries :). Glad we got there in the end! Have a good one!